# How to customize wso2 api manager error format?

Tags: wso2

I've deployed wso2 API manager v3.2 in k8s  , i want to know how to customize the error format and make it permenent .

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the error message by using the custom sequence below.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/error-handling/#custom-error-messages

Comment: To make those changes permenent do i need to build a new docker image ?

Comment: You have 2 options. 1. Burn these artifacts to the docker image. 2. Use a configmap and mount these artifacts to the container.